# Multiple Greater than symbol (>) in result of T-SQL when run with shell script

Tags: sql-server, shell, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a report using SQL Server Management Studio and running script using T-SQL and shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

result=`tsql -S devserver -p 6230 -U user -P password <<EOF

USE devdb
go

select top 1 SampleDate "LastSampleDate" from close with(nolock) order by SampleDate asc
go
select top 1 SampleDate "TopSampleDate" from close_history with(nolock)  order by SampleDate desc
go
select count(1) "history_count" from close_history with(nolock)
GO
select count(1) "count" from close with(nolock)
GO
select convert(varchar, dateadd(day, -190, GETDATE()), 23) "LastDayAfterRunInHistory"
GO
exit
EOF`

echo "now iterate ..."
let rec=0


while read line; do
      echo "processing $rec: $line"
            let rec=rec+1
done <<< "${result}"
```

Above scripts is giving following result -

```
now iterate ...
processing 0: locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
processing 1: locale charset is "UTF-8"
processing 2: using default charset "UTF-8"
processing 3: locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
processing 4: locale charset is "UTF-8"
processing 5: using default charset "UTF-8"
processing 6: 1> 2> 3> 1> 2> 3> LastSampleDate
processing 7: 2022-01-11
processing 8: (1 row affected)
processing 9: 1> 2> TopSampleDate
processing 10: 2022-01-10
processing 11: (1 row affected)
processing 12: 1> 2> history_count
processing 13: 13824580
processing 14: (1 row affected)
processing 15: 1> 2> count
processing 16: 2857074
processing 17: (1 row affected)
processing 18: 1> 2> LastDayAfterRunInHistory
processing 19: 2022-02-03
processing 20: (1 row affected)
processing 21: 1>
```

It seems for each go statement, I am getting these - "1> 2> 3> 1> 2> 3> ".
Is there any way to remove it so I can read result easily.

Comment: Those NOLOCK hints are very likely not a good idea. They have pretty interesting affects on your results. https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere

Comment: My other applications are using same tables so I need to use nolock to save me from locks

Comment: Read the link I posted. That hint does not "save you from locks", it gives you dirty reads. And when using aggregates it can and will return incorrect numbers because when using the NOLOCK hint you can have some rows skipped and some rows read twice.

Comment: What does `tsql --help` have to say about things? Have you tried the `-oq` option for "quiet" output?